# I have an error "SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'cobaognm_cobary'@'localhost' to database 'cobaognm_cobary'" on a laravel application

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I created a database, User and password on cpanel. I've written down the username, password and database that i've created, in my env file:

[image]

But every time I try to load my website page it says, "SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'cobaognm_cobary'@'localhost' to database 'cobaognm_cobary'".

Normally, in my experience, when I've used "cpanel", in the past, I've never had to do more than this.

But I find myself stuck. What can I do next?

I've gone online and I've tried other solutions on Stack Overflow, regarding a similar problem. But nothing has worked for me, so far. The error has persisted.

Comment: The user/pass for your database is incorrect, or that user doesn't have access to that database. CPanel usually logs in with a root user, so you don't have to worry about permissions.

Comment: Double-check with your hosting provider (if the info is not visible in cPanel in the screen where you configure the DB users) whether you have to do anything else, like set a different hostname. Otherwise, I would suggest you perhaps accidentally copied the credentials incorrectly, or perhaps you forgot to grant the new user access to that specific database. We cannot tell, just from a picture of the error.

Comment: The mistake was mine. I created a user and then a database, without giving the user permission to access the database. I've done that now, thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you linked the user to that database?

In cPanel, when you create a new database and an user, you should add the permissions for that user on your database.

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360057550753-How-to-create-a-database-and-database-user-in-cPanel

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the database settings and modify the user settings and give him all the permissions to make sure that you did it well. Go to phpmyadmin and try logging in with it and verify the permissions.

Comment: The mistake was mine. I created a user and then a database, without giving the user permission to access the database. I've done that now, thank you all for your suggestions.